# Eclipse: How to see methods supported by variable's type during debugging ?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

During editing Eclipse gives suggestions for the methods that I can call on a variable. Is there a way to see those suggestions during debugging, maybe in the variables window or maybe in some other perspective ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, I just needed to click on Show Type Hierarchy

Comment: If you are able to answer your own question please accept it so other users with the same problem can see the answer quickly.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't...you should always use the editor and the content assistant (be careful don't change source code otherwise the debugger will complain)